# SecondaryTile with unicode character in DisplayName

Tags: unicode, uwp, win-universal-app

I am using this piece of code to create a `SecondaryTile`.

```
    public static async Task<bool> PinToStartAsync(Playlist playlist, bool isPlaylist)
    {
        var tilename = playlist.Name;
        var tileid = Uri.EscapeDataString(isPlaylist ? tilename : $"{tilename}+++{playlist.Artist}");
        var filename = Uri.EscapeDataString(tilename);
        var path = LogoPath;
        if (playlist.DisplayItem.Source != null && await (await GetSecondaryTileFolder()).TryGetItemAsync(filename) == null)
        {
            await (await GetStorageItemThumbnailAsync(playlist.DisplayItem.Source.Path)).SaveAsync(SecondaryTileFolder, filename);
            path = $"ms-appdata:///local/SecondaryTiles/{filename}.png";
        }
        var tile = new SecondaryTile(tileid, tilename, isPlaylist.ToString(), new Uri(path), TileSize.Default);
        tile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo = tile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare310x310Logo = tile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnWide310x150Logo = true;
        if (SecondaryTile.Exists(tilename)) await tile.RequestDeleteAsync();
        else await tile.RequestCreateAsync();
        return SecondaryTile.Exists(tilename);
    }
```

This piece of code works fine when the playlist name is like 123 or helloworld. However, when I use unicode in the `tilename`, it causes problem.

Below is an image of `SecondaryTile`s that I created. The name of first two has some unicode characters.

[image]

So it is not able to display the `Thumbnail` I stored locally, even though I created those images successfully.

[image]

Another problem with unicode character is that, the `SecondaryTile.Exists(tilename)` will always return false.

I have noticed the problem with unicode so I added `Uri.EscapeDataString` to `tileid` and `filename` so that they are uri safe. However, I do want my tiles to have names with unicode characters.

How should I allow unicode characters in `tilename`?

---Code Update---

```
    public static async Task<bool> PinToStartAsync(Playlist playlist, bool isPlaylist)
    {
        var tilename = playlist.Name;
        var tileid = WebUtility.UrlEncode(isPlaylist ? tilename : $"{tilename}+++{playlist.Artist}");
        var filename = tileid + ".png";
        var path = DefaultAlbumCoverPath;
        if (playlist.DisplayItem.Source != null && !await (await GetSecondaryTileFolder()).Contains(filename))
        {
            await (await GetStorageItemThumbnailAsync(playlist.DisplayItem.Source.Path)).SaveAsync(SecondaryTileFolder, tileid);
            path = $"ms-appdata:///local/SecondaryTiles/" + filename;
        }
        var tile = new SecondaryTile(tileid, tilename, isPlaylist.ToString(), new Uri(path), TileSize.Default);
        tile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo = tile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare310x310Logo = tile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnWide310x150Logo = true;
        if (SecondaryTile.Exists(tileid)) await tile.RequestDeleteAsync();
        else await tile.RequestCreateAsync();
        return SecondaryTile.Exists(tileid);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `SecondaryTile` accesses the image through the path, the entire URI must be path-safe, which is a prerequisite for the software to successfully access the image.

From this perspective, there is nothing wrong with your handling.

<del>In fact, these images are stored in the application's local storage and are not publicly available. The name doesn't need to be concerned. 

But you can translate the image name via `Uri.UnescapeDataString()` when exporting these images or you want to get its name.</del>

---

**Update**

As you can see from the picture you gave, the tile can display Chinese text (although it is illegible because it is white background + white text), so your question appears on the image.

You don't have to use `Uri.EscapeDataString` to change the file name, which will exceed the limit when converting long filenames.

You can save the image as the original name, but you can use the following methods when using the link:

```cs
string imagePath = $"ms-appdata:///local/SecondaryTiles/{WebUtility.UrlEncode("测试图片")}.png";
```

Using `WebUtility.UrlEncode()` in the link can solve this problem well, and the image will be recognized normally.

> Another problem with unicode character is that, the SecondaryTile.Exists(tilename) will always return false.

This has nothing to do with Unicode, the main problem is your code:

```cs
if (SecondaryTile.Exists(tilename)) 
    await tile.RequestDeleteAsync();
else 
    await tile.RequestCreateAsync();
```

Your code has a key problem. When it detects the Tile with the same id, it only deletes it, but does not create a new Tile, so it naturally returns false when it detects.

Best regards.

Comment: I am not asking about the image path. The problem is my `tilename`. It contains Chinese characters which makes it not recognizable.

Comment: But `SecondaryTile.Exists(tilename)` doesn't involve with `tileid`.

Comment: The argument to `SecondaryTile.Exists()` is `tileid` instead of `tilename`, you create a tile using `tileid`, but look it up with `tilename` and you will never find it. For image. When you save the album cover image locally and point it with the correct link, the tile will display the image.

Comment: Oh that's `tileid`...I am so silly...Could you please look at my updated code? Using `WebUtility` doesn't make a difference for me. The image is generated locally but it is not pointing to it.

Comment: Correctly speaking, it is possibly pointing to it. Because not pointing to an existing image gives me my logo instead of whiteness.

Comment: Sorry, this makes me confused. Have you compared the image name generated in `LocalFolder`? You can try adding this section to the code: `var localImage = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri( $"ms-appdata:///local/SecondaryTiles/{WebUtility.UrlEncode(filename)}")) `, can this code gets the picture?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201575/discussion-between-seaky-and-richard-zhang-msft).